# How to handle binary(Blob) data in Spring Batch application

Tags: oracle, jdbc, spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-transactions

My requirement is reading data from a Database aggregate it and convert to bytes  then stream it to another database(Oracle) in a Blob column.

Oracle requires to disable JDBC autocommit to stream to a Blob column and call Connection#Commit when finished.

I currently have 3 steps.

**Step 1**(Tasklet): 
It has two SQL queries. one to initialize the column (`UPDATE DATABASEUSER.TABLENAME SET payload = empty_blob() WHERE PrimaryKey= ?`)

the second one returns the Blob locator (`SELECT payload AS payload FROM DATABASEUSER.TABLENAME WHERE PrimaryKey = ? FOR UPDATE`)

I also get the connection object from the datasource to disable autocommit

**Step 2**(Chuck)
I have an IteamReader that reads data from the source DB in a generic way and a Processor that takes converts the rows to a CSV format but in bytes. Then I have a Custom ItemWriter to stream the data to the Blob column.

**Step 3**(Tasklet)
This is when I cleanup and commit the connection.

Question 1: Is this the correct strategy? Appreciate any direction as I'm kinda unsure

Comment: No. You can't hold a transaction across steps. Each step must commit on its own.

Comment: @DeanClark I solved it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

I used the ResourcelessTransactionManager transaction manager in all my steps. In step 1 I get a connection from the datasource, disable autocommit and call commit on the final step. I use the same connection in all steps.